# How to make a login frame display in the center of the window when the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just like what happens when you click *Sign in with OpenID* on http://twitterfeed.com/, I want my login frame displays in the center of the window, and only when some link is clicked.

But now I have difficult to center a div, I have written CSS as following but it doesn't work

```
#logindiv {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position/styling of the div can be emulated with:

```
#overlay_div {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: #000;
}

#overlay_div #logindiv {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left:50%;
height: 20em;
width: 40em;
margin: -10em 0 0 -20em;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

The top left corner of the `#logindiv` is positioned absolutely at a point 50% across the width of the window and 50% of the height of the window (from the top-left origin).

This is then altered by the `margin`s, moving it 50% of its height up the page, and 50% of its width back across the page. Changing the width/height of the `#logindiv` will require different negative margins for positioning centrally.

Answer (score 1):

"position: related;" is a typo. It should be "position: relative;"

Looking at the site you linked to, it's horizontally centered but not vertically centered. They achieved that by using a table with a single row and a single column.

Comment: How does the site make the <div class="rpx_popup_overlay"> floating on the other divs? I have set attributes including position, overflow, z-index all the same as that site, but it still stays in the top of the page.